# Indentation based Grammars

Tags: formal-grammars, compilers, parsers

Considering programming languages with significant whitespace for indentation, such as Python or Haskell. How does this whitespace fit into the grand schemes of programming language grammars.

I can see that a "preprocessor" can convert indent changes into tokens which are then handled in grammars, yet can one also perform the parsing based upon a single grammar without changing the intrinsic complexity of the 2nd grammer?

Comment: Most programming languages are handled by two phases, lexical analysis (the toknization phase you talk above) and syntax analysis (the syntax itself, in tokens). So this isn't an extra burden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any modern compiler consists of multiple phases, at least

1. [lexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis),
2. (context-free) [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) and
3. target code generation.

Additional phases are static analysis (names, types, ...) and optimisations.
Each phase uses the result of the prior as input.

Now, the lexer processes the actual program text and transforms it into a token stream. For instance, the (sub)string `"abc"` becomes a token `StringLiteral("abc")`, `if` becomes `IF` and `myMethod` becomes `Identifier("myMethod")`. Tokens typically hold additional information, e.g. their position in the original program text. The context-free grammar used for syntax parsing is expressed in terms of these tokens, usually ignoring their parameters.

At this point, it should be clear that handling whitespace is nothing crazy: instead of dropping all whitespace (like a Java compiler would do), you could as easily lex the strings `"  "` or `\t` to a token `Indentation` used in the grammar.